# Web Browser in c# Winforms

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Using Internet Explorer, our company can navigate through an intranet and we can interact with BACnet modules that display values, change values or setpoints, it's basically an energy management purpose. We can see the temperature in rooms and change a large amount of info using internet explorer.

While in IE we can press CTRL "M" and a dialog box pops up and if you type "whoson" and press ok another popup displays users that are currently logged on. Or if we are pointing at a particular module and press CTRL "M" and type "modstat" the popup will display module status(it lets you know if its talking, has been downloaded, etc).

This is all in Internet explorer...I have created a tabbed Windows form with Webbrowser control and the look is perfect when I log on to a customers intranet...but when I press CTRL "m" and ask for information about a particular module("modstat" or anything else) the popup starts but never displays information. I have read about embedded browser but I am a week programmer and I just dont get it or there's not any good information. I have spent months working on this program (re-writing code to make it....perfect) I don't want it to end here because it's useless if I cant get that to work.

Comment: Have a look here http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/12/23/1330.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the information, I found the same implamentaion here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtendedWebBrowser.aspx I need to go through the code to understand it but it works!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you right, it sounds like this BACnet module is an Internet Explorer BHO (browser helper object). BHO's are not loaded in the WebBrowser control as they are in the full IE, which could be why you're not seing anything. For how to enable them, take a look at this answer - [Want to enable BHO in a WebBrowser Control embedded in a standard C# App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419653/want-to-enable-bho-in-a-webbrowser-control-embedded-in-a-standard-c-sharp-app)